# Dell XPS not sleeping

Tags: sleep, dell-xps

My Dell XPS 15 doesn't seem to sleep when I close the lid. I'll close it at night and when I open it in the morning the battery will be completely drained. I checked `powercfg -requests` but all categories show `None`. Any ideas as to what could be preventing sleep?

Comment: You will need to check a setting in the Control Panel's power settings to allow the machine to sleep when the lid is closed.

Comment: I checked my power settings and my profile was on High Performance. That explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, there is a setting to keep the screen on and the computer awake even when the lid is closed.

This can be changed through the Control Panel -> Power Settings, and either changing the entire power plan to Balanced, or editing the  power plan to change the setting for when the lid is closed.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't check this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I had an issue where my laptop was going into hibernate even though I was asking for it to stay in sleep mode longer. After generating powercfg /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT I noticed Drain (dozed to hibernate because the standby battery budget was exceeded). After searching this came up and also this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/adaptive-hibernate which basically states that windows will transition to hibernate once a certain amount of battery is drained (even if the hibernate timer has not kicked in) Apparently this is powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent 60 will increase that percentage

Answer (score 0):

XPS 15 7590 in 2019 requires a slightly different approach.

First, you can make sure that your Connected Standby is draining your battery and placing your computer into hibernation:

```
 # run in admin PowerShell:
 powercfg.exe /systempowerreport /output $home\Desktop\power-report.html
 # open in browser:
 file:///C:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/power-report.html
```

If you see "Drain (dozed to hibernate because the standby battery budget was exceeded)", then the following can help.

Normally, you would turn off Connected Standby altogether by setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power CsEnabled = 0`, but due to an issue with the WiFi/Bluetooth adapter, you will completely lose Bluetooth on every wake up.

This worked for me (in the context of Connected Standby):

1. Go to `Windows Settings -> Power & Sleep -> Network Connection -> Disconnect from the network -> Always`
2. Open an admin PowerShell and run (you must have Chocolatey installed; alternatively you can install NSudo manually):

   ```
    choco install -y nsudo
   ```
3. Open a new PowerShell window without restrictions:

   ```
    nsudo -U:S -P:E powershell
   ```
4. In that window, disable tasks which torture your computer
   when you leave it idle for a few minutes:

   ```
    Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Disabled" -and $_.Triggers -match "MSFT_TaskIdleTrigger"} | Disable-ScheduledTask
   ```
5. Disable tasks which deplete your battery in Connected Standby, placing your computer in hibernation, and severely slowing the next startup when you open the lid:

   ```
    Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Disabled" -and $_.settings.waketorun } | Disable-ScheduledTask
   ```

#### UPDATE 25/06/2020:

I've since found a better solution - increase the standby battery consumption budget from 5% to 60%. This will make it through the occasional night of being turned off without being on charger.

```
  powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent 60
```

Comment: I don't understand what increasing the standby budget does. Does it avoid the laptop heating and battery drain when in modern standby?

Comment: @HermanToothrot it won't get hybernated / turned off. I don't have the issue of the laptop overheating on standby. Seems like your laptop is not even sleeping / is not on standby. Try Disable Network in the active sleep, or what is it called.